# How can I print a certain string depending on the row value in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns A, B and C in the excel sheet which contain some dimensions:
[image]

I need to calculate and print the volume(length x width x height) in column E.
Once I have the volume, based on the value I will need to label it as Small, Medium or Large in Column F.

I need to do this using VBA.

P.S: This is just sample data, actual data will be a lot more so the range needs to be dynamic.

I tried the following piece of code but I am getting error on the line marked with '*'.
The part where I need to calculate the volume is working fine but the labelling logic is the problem. The error I am getting is 'Type Mismatch'.

```
Sub test()
Dim LR
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E3:E" & LR).Formula = "=B3*C3*D3"
Range("E3:E" & LR).Value = Range("E3:E" & LR).Value

*If Range("E3:E" & LR).Value < 1000000 Then
   Range("F3:F" & LR).Value = "Small"
ElseIf Range("E3:E" & LR).Value >= 1000000 And Range("E3:E" & LR).Value <= 9000000 Then
    Range("F3:F" & LR).Value = "Medium"
Else
    Range("F3:F" & LR).Value = "Large"
End If
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA so not sure what am I doing wrong. Please can someone help me with this.

Comment: You need to loop through the range, you can't compare an entire array to a long in one shot.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in VBA? That looks like yiu can just use a basic lookup formula?

Comment: @dbmitch I am practicing VBA.

Comment: @Warcupine could you please show me how?

Comment: Use a loop like @Warcupine suggested earlier

Comment: You _can_ used the same formula-based approach you used to populate column E, e.g. 
`Range("F3:F" & LR).Formula = "=IF(E3<1000000,""SMALL"",IF(E3<=9000000,""Medium"",""LARGE""))"`